# How can we view the databases/tables created in phpmyadmin in the MySQL workbench schemas section?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

How can we view the databases/tables created in phpmyadmin in the MySQL workbench schemas section? In my case the database created in the phpmyadmin are not reflected in workbench(v-6.3) and mysql server v-5.7.12.How can I check that the phpmyadmin used is reflecting the correct workbench.

I am running the phpmyadmin locally (XAMPP 5.6.20-0) and I am using Mac OS X El-capitan. Is the import only option copy all databases/tables created in phpmyadmin into MySQL and visa versa?Please advice

Answer (score 0):

As long as MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin are connected to the same MySQL instance, any changes made in one program should immediately be visible from the other. You might be restricted if you're connecting as different, non-administrative users who doesn't have access to the same databases.

From each program (MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin), issue the `STATUS;` SQL command and compare the host and port or socket. If they don't match, you would seem to have more than one MySQL installed on your machine.

The fact that you have specifically mentioned installing MySQL server and XAMPP makes this highly likely; XAMPP comes with its own version of MySQL server and you should pick one to access from both client programs to minimize confusion.